# Auto resize input fields in HTML

Tags: html

What do I have to do, so the inputs from the table will get smaller if I minimize the browser window? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type=text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=text>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td>
                <input type=text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=text>
            </td>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use percent in your css to resize

```
<style>
input[type="text"]{
  width:10%;/* Whatever percent you want*/
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style>
    input 
  { 
    width:100%; 
    height: 100%; 
   }
 </style>
```

also add:

```
<table cellspacing="5px">
```

Hope this helps you